# Display progress using pop-up in Winwrapbasic language

Tags: progress, winwrap

Is there a way to display a pop-up text box in WinWrap Basic to update the user about the progress of the code?

The progress can be in the form of text which changes as the code runs and needs to be displayed in the pop-up.

Something like **wscript.echo** which displays the progress in the command window would also be fine. However, such a function doesn't seem to be available for WinWrap Basic language.

Message box and user dialog don't appear to be the solution as they require the user to click a button for them to close and code to proceed.

Any advice would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the existing user dialog features available in Winwrapbasic language can handle such a requirement.

The following link describes a possible solution:

http://kb.awr.com/display/scripts/Scripting+How-To%3A+Creating+a+Dialog+with+Status+Text+and+a+Progress+Bar+in+AWR+Scripting

I am yet to incorporate this solution but this appears to satisfy my requirements.